# Matching any phrase with a boolean (and, or, not) keyword that is contained within double quotes? (JS Regex)

Tags: javascript, regex

Using the JS Flavor or regex.

I'm trying to match double quoted phrases that contain atleast 1 boolean keyword (and, or, not, AND, OR, NOT).

In the following test cases, for example, I would only want to match the bold & italic segment

"cat" or "dog" and ***"cat not dog"***

"cat" or "dog" and ***"cat or dog"***

"cat" or "dog" and ***"cat and dog"***

Comment: I have this regex for matching any double quoted phrase, but this is not as specific as required.

/".*?"/g

Comment: you can do a case insensitive match with `"[^"]+ (not|or|and) [^"]+"`

Comment: I think if I want case insensitive booleans I can do `"[^"]+ (not|or|and|NOT|OR|AND) [^"]+"` right? unless there is better way to explicitly type out in all caps booleans

Comment: Hey vishal if you create an answer to this question, I will mark it as answer so you can get karma points! thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`/"([^"]+ (not|or|and) [^"]+)"/gi` will pass all tests and capture the segments you highlighted in bold & italic in the first capture group.

Here's a [demonstration](https://regexr.com/5p4mk) on the Javascript browser engine.

Comment: Hey Kad thanks but I'd like to give Vishal the answer because he responded first

Comment: It's unfortunate Vishal never posted his answer! Your question is still listed as unanswered... :-)